# Items won't display

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from item.models import ItemCategory, Item
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('order.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'category/$', 'category'),
    url(r'(?P<cat_id>\d+)/$', 'item'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from item.models import ItemCategory, Item
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def item(request, cat_id):
    item_list = get_object_or_404(ItemCategory, pk=cat_id)
    return render_to_response('order/item.html', {'item_list':item_list})
```

item.html

```
{% if item_list %}
    <h3>{{ item_list.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for item in item_list.choice_set.all %}
            <li>{{ item.id }} - {{ item.item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

given the above codes, it should display:

#### category 1

```
- item 1
- item 2
```

but it's only displaying like this:

#### category 1

it doesn't display the items

what is the possibly wrong on this?

Comment: You forgot to add your `models.py` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy this code from the tutorial? Is the connected model called `choice_set` intentionally? If your `Item` model has `ForeignKey(ItemCategory)`, then it should be `item_set`. But that's just a pure guess.

I'd put a debug line in the view, before it returns, and check if the item has those choices in choice_set. Issues are much to fix if you have a debugger and can see what's really happening rather than reading code and guessing.

```
def item(request, cat_id):
    item_list = get_object_or_404(ItemCategory, pk=cat_id)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return render_to_response('order/item.html', {'item_list':item_list})
```

or better IPDB (you'll have to install it with easy_install or pip)

```
def item(request, cat_id):
    item_list = get_object_or_404(ItemCategory, pk=cat_id)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    return render_to_response('order/item.html', {'item_list':item_list})
```

In the debugger, write the variable and check if it's what you expect:

```
>>> item_list
[some output]
>>> item_list.choice_set.all()
[some output]
```

(Offtopic) There's django_annoying app with useful shortcuts:

```
from annoying.decorators import render_to

@render_to('order/item.html')
def item(request, cat_id):
    item_list = get_object_or_404(ItemCategory, pk=cat_id)
    return {'item_list':item_list}
```